# Is it possible to use ts-jest / jest to spy on a generic function and mock a return value in Typescript environment?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am new user trying to learn jest in a Typescript environment via ts-jest. One of the functions that I wish to 'spyOn' uses generics. Is it possible to spy on a generic function and mock a typed return value?

For example:

```js
export class Api {
  private api: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(api: AxiosInstance = axios) {
    this.api = api;
  }

  public all<T, From = T, TF extends ITransform<From, T> = never>(
    url: string,
    transformer?: TF,
  ): Observable<AxiosResponse<T[]>> {
    return this.requestAll<T, From, TF>(url, transformer);
  }
```

I have tried with:

```
const allSpy = jest.spyOn<Api, 'all'>(Api.prototype, 'all');
```

In this case *allSpy* has the following type information:

```js
const allSpy: jest.SpyInstance<Observable<AxiosResponse<unknown[]>>, [string, (ITransform<any, any> | undefined)?]>
```

I receive a type compilation error if I try to mock a return value:

```js
 const response: AxiosResponse<MyObj[]> = {
      data: [
        { id: 1014760, objName: 'Object 1' },
        { id: 1015762, objName: 'Object 2' },
      ],
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'ok',
      headers: {},
      config: {},
    };
allSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(response); // type error for response
```

Comment: You're spying on something that returns an observable of a value, but returning the value. TS is telling you the right thing; that's incorrect.

Comment: So how would I be able to spy on the all method?

Comment: You're *already* spying on it. The point is that you have to return the right kind of thing, that's where the error is coming: `.mockReturnValueOnce(of(response))`

Comment: Many thanks, @jonrsharpe, got it, mocking an observable of the response.  Do you want to post answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score -1):

Try to stub instead spy and you'll be able to get it.